# Where is the edit button?

Tags: contacts

I have created a user that belongs to a group. I have rights to edit contacts from that group. However I can only edit in the "quick view", but the button for editing the whole profile has disappeared. From the advanced search I can see that "edit" link...
Why? How can I restore it?
Thanks!

[image: where is the edit button]
[image: edit link from advanced search]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any custom CSS or java script?  Do you see a reference to the edit button if you check the page source?

Comment: No, the edit button is not hidden with CSS, it doesn't appear either in the page source :\

Comment: Do you have any customizations?  What version of CiviCRM are you running and with what CMS